# Ohwait... mods on strike? Time for a few days of honest, forthright comments!

Tags: discussion

Ok, so the mods are on strike for well-known reasons.  I might be a bit slow on this, but it only just occurred to me - a mod strike means a suspension strike!

So, maybe the long-suffering curators have a few days to 'strike' back against the hopeless, selfish deadbeats who just want their entire assignments done, their plagiarized code dumps debugged and/or leave it up to others to provide links to their pan-galactic gargle FAQ's.

Yes, perhaps the ChatGPT issue and strike, unfortunate as it is overall, might be.... dare I say it.....

Fun?

Comment: What are you trying to discuss here? Plus, this post comes across as somewhat condescending; it *needs* a reword.

Comment: Note that not _all_ moderators on Stack Overflow are on strike. Try something funny deliberately, and it may get to you eventually, even if just after the strike is over.

Comment: At some point after the strike, the flags will be handled. Sure, you might not be banned today, but is it worth being banned in a week? And isn't there an auto-ban when you collect too many rude/abusive flags?

Comment: @BDL spoiler: no, there's no ban for comments only :(

Comment: Lol:)  You can troll mods even when they are on strike:)  Condescending?  Bah!

Comment: No, you can't troll mods when they are on strike; you aren't to troll anyone here, mods, curator, help vampire, casual user, etc. If you're here to troll, then you'll still suffer the usual consequences, just later. If you *really* abuse the situation, I don't doubt that one of the non-striking mods will deal with the matter.

Comment: @MartinJames, I'd assume that what you see a chance to do might be classified as R/A, and it's pretty reasonable to believe that those mods how aren't on strike, mostly look into this kind of flags. So, poster's discretion is advised.

Comment: "long-suffering curators". I can take all the arm waving but this right here raises my temperature a little. Yes it is suffering to do something voluntarily. You can just stop doing it if it is really so bad for you.

Comment: uh, that's not the point of the strike?

Comment: A community user I am actively not improving contributions because of the strike, but I am flagging spam, and downvoting absolute trash contributions.  Garbage will be flagged, and it will eventually be moderated.

Comment: [oops, my anarchy symbol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry5URU-Py2Q)

Comment: While I agree that this post is more an opinion of the OP and not a discussion, I also agree with it's sentiment. Some mods want to strike and that's fine, it's their choice, but I find it hypocritical that they also get to keep their account's mod privileges as well. This comes with access to privileged tools and data, including site statistics and user information. If they don't want to moderate they don't need to keep access to these privileges either. There should be a way to revoke this access at least for the duration of the non-moderation period.

Comment: @user13267, I don't see, how your statement related to authors sentiment. Maybe it is wrong post for this comment? [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390073)'s one better. But regardless: why bother revoke diamond and then reinstate more then a hundred mods, if [SE is sure, that this will end shortly](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/12/internal_messages.html)?

Comment: @markalex may be I misread the author's sentiment may be not, but the comment is my point of view regardless. And as to "why bother", it's not about bothering or not bothering, if that makes sense, but it's about access to privileged site/user information, that the accounts on strike still have, which they shouldn't have access to at least for the duration of the strike, imho. If you feel this strongly about the issue, also be ready to forfeit the privileges.

Comment: What would you *possibly* hope to accomplish by doing this? If you just want to troll people, there are websites for that. You don't need to do it here.

Answer (score 23):

#### This is not that kind of strike.

People are striking from curating the platform due to the ill faithed communication and moderation policies from Stack Overflow Inc. imposed on the community.
This is not a strike against the established policies of being nice,
nor it is against the old or new code of conduct. Being rude is also not the way that we intend to strike,

As such, regardless of whoever you are "other"ing and pointing fingers at, this strike is not about that, and you are not being given any excuse from poor behavior.  You would just be painting yourself a bad image.

> Yes, perhaps the ChatGPT issue and strike, unfortunate as it is overall, might be.... dare I say it.....
>
> Fun?

There is nothing fun about the site slowly becoming a garbage dump, but this is what has been decided to make a point.

Comment: "Ill faithed". Is that a typo... or creative writing?

Comment: @Gimby Probably a mix of both. I mean to say _"in bad faith"_.

Comment: "bad faith" works as an adjectival phrase, too.

Answer (score 15):

### Don't make Stack Overflow worse; make other places better

If you have time and creative energy to burn, start (or work on) a blog and show off the content you might have created otherwise.

- If you normally write answers for one-off questions, here's an opportunity to set your own questions (of course, [you always had that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but now you have an explicit impetus), generalize the problems that you keep seeing, and stop worrying about the lack of a canonical.
- If you normally work to identify those canonicals, you can publish blog articles on a general topic (rather than a question) and have them heavily cite (not plagiarize, of course; Stack Overflow's content [license requires attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)) existing Q&A.
- If you normally tell people off for using the site wrong, you can write blog posts about how the site is (was) intended to work, and defend the value of that model.
- If you normally write quick answers to chase a quick upvote and accept for 25 more reputation - here's a chance to reform yourself. Break that cycle of addiction and take charge of the content you're writing. If you really need the dopamine of numbers going up, install a hit counter or something.
- If you want the site to become worse to further the goals of those on strike - well, people already see the site as "toxic" and "mean", no matter what policies we implement to counter that; and they have for years. If the site becomes seen as a place that *doesn't answer questions any more*, then that's an actual degradation. If they see that there are *other* places that *do* answer questions, so much the better. (Although it will almost certainly be better for your sanity to do so on a personal blog than on a discussion forum.)

Comment: Yes, self-hosted content, like blogs, is the way to go. Despite the intent, Stack Overflow has largely failed to provide non-redundant high-quality reference material. Or at least the search engines refuse to point to it (posts from 2008-2009).